# For fixed $n, c \in \mathbb{N}$ find all natural number pairs $(a,b)$ to $a +nb = c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I arrived at this problem as I am trying to find a discrete probability distribution of trying to catch a frog hopping on a number line using a particular method of counting [When the frog initial position (a) and step size (b) is within finite intervals].

For fixed $n, c \in \mathbb{N}$ find all natural number pairs $(a,b)$ to $a +nb = c$.

How does one go about such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible values for $b$ are $0,1,2,...,floor(\frac{c}{n})$ , where floor
 means removing the fractional part. You get $a$ by inserting $b$ in $a=c-nb$

Answer (score 1):

Find $j,k$ by $j = \left \lfloor \frac{c}{n} \right \rfloor $ and $k = c -nj$.

Then $\{(a,b)\}$ is $\{(k+ni,j-i)\}$ for $i=0,\ldots j$ (excluding the last element and perhaps the first if zero is not regarded as within the natural numbers).